# Is there any way to make Next JS APIs respond to only requests coming from frontend? I am using Next 13

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I want to block any other apis to be able to access one of my NEXT API endpoints. Is there a way to configure in NEXT 13? I am using app based directory and new NEXT 13 features.

Here's an example:

```
// This code is added in one of the client components
useEffect(() => {
        cacheFetch(apiRoutes.GET_TOKEN, { noCache: true }).then((result) => {
            console.log('Result = ', result);
        });
    }, []);
```

Here's the middleware as suggested by @Yilmaz:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
enum MiddlewareRoutes {
    GET_TOKEN = '/api/get-token',
}

const middlewareHandler = async (
    route: MiddlewareRoutes,
    request: NextRequest,
    response: NextResponse
): Promise<NextResponse> => {
    switch (route) {
        case MiddlewareRoutes.GET_TOKEN: {
            const fromFE = request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/api');
            console.log('From Frontent = ', fromFE);
            return response;
        }
        default: {
            return response;
        }
    }
};

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const response = NextResponse.next();
    const newResponse = await middlewareHandler(
        (request?.nextUrl?.pathname ?? '') as MiddlewareRoutes,
        request,
        response
    );
    return newResponse;
}

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/api/:path*'],
};
```

Now expected outcome is:
`curl http://localhost:3000/api/get-token` should log: From Frontent =  false
and
when request send by the useEffect block should log:
From Frontent =  true

But in both the cases it returns true. Can someone help me here to make middleware fromFrontend variable false when it comes from my NEXT JS frontend?

I wouldn't want to inject a query parameter unless it gets injected internally as it could be spoofed otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const response = NextResponse.next()

  if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/api")) {
    response.headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "yourDomainHere")
  }
  
  return response
}
```

Comment: Hey @Yilmaz. I have added more details Can you please check again?

Comment: did u add this: `response.headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "yourDomainHere")`

Comment: yes I did. This seems like a bug with next 13 middleware. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76546717/next-13-middleware-unexpected-behaviour-caching-request-or-returning-same-res