# Next 13 - Middleware unexpected behaviour: Caching request or returning same response without validation?

Tags: next.js

My NEXT 13 middleware seems to cache results in an unexpected way but the response is always new. I suspect that middleware gets called only once if I have two APIs to invoke. Here's how my middleware looks:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { config as appConfig } from '@/config/config';
enum MiddlewareRoutes {
    ACCESS = '/api/access',
    GET_TOKEN = '/api/get-token',
}

const middlewareHandler = async (
    route: MiddlewareRoutes,
    request: NextRequest,
    response: NextResponse
): Promise<NextResponse> => {
    switch (route) {
        case MiddlewareRoutes.ACCESS: {
            const { token } = await fetch(
                `${request.nextUrl.origin}/api/get-token`
            ).then((res) =>
                res.json().then((data) => {
                    return data;
                })
            );
            if (!token) {
                console.log('Empty response');
                return response;
            }
            response.cookies.set({
                name: 'x-access-token',
                value: token,
                path: '/',
            });
            return response;
        }
        case MiddlewareRoutes.GET_TOKEN: {
            const apiKey =
                request?.nextUrl?.href?.split?.('apiKey=')?.[1]?.replace?.('&', '') ??
                '';
            console.log('Comes in', !apiKey || apiKey !== appConfig.BACKEND_API_KEY);
            if (!apiKey || apiKey !== appConfig.BACKEND_API_KEY)
                return NextResponse.json(null, {
                    status: 401,
                    statusText: 'Unauthorized to make request',
                });
            else return response;
        }
        default: {
            return response;
        }
    }
};

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const response = NextResponse.next();
    const newResponse = await middlewareHandler(
        (request?.nextUrl?.pathname ?? '') as MiddlewareRoutes,
        request,
        response
    );
    return newResponse;
}

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/api/:path*'],
};
```

Now my `access` API invokes `get-token` API. But middleware only acts once. Is this some bug in NEXT 13 or am I doing something wrong?